# Add a directory which previously had its own git repository

Tags: git, git-submodules

I had Git a project with other Git project inside. 
I finally decided to remove the second one, so I removed the `.git` directory:

```
rm -rf /pathToProject/pathToProjectInsideProject/.git
```

But now, when I do `git status` I can't see the changes on the `pathToProject/pathToProjectInsideProject/` directory.

I've try with:

```
git add pathToProjectInsideProject
```

but nothing changes. Any idea of how to include this directory to the main git repository?

**Edit:**

When I try to add a single file with `force` (`git add --force pathToProjectInsideProject/file.php`) I'm getting this error:

> pathToProjectInsideProject/file.php is in submodule pathToProjectInsideProject

**Edit2:**

This question is duplicate: [How do I add files in Git to the path of a former submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574625/how-do-i-add-files-in-git-to-the-path-of-a-former-submodule).

The solution is:

```
git rm --cached pathToProjectInsideProject
git add pathToProjectInsideProject
```

Comment: Did you try `git add --all` ?

Comment: @VinayVeluri - Well, there are some files that I don't want to add. Just want to add all files and folders on the mentioned directory.

Comment: Have you had submodules?

Comment: @martin - That's it. Didn't know that term.

Comment: your subdir Git is configured as a Git submodule. You have to remove this submodule if you want to add files from it (delete it from .gitmodules files)

Comment: @pomeh - I don't find any `.gitmodules` file. I've just deleted the `.git` directory in `pathToProjectInsideProject`.

Comment: if you have it, it's located at the same level as your top `.git` dir. If you don't have it, then you might have some `.gitignore` file somewhere with a rule to ignore that subdir

Comment: @pomeh - Don't have it. Also tried `find ./ -name .gitignore` and just have one, and don't ingnore that subdirectory.

Comment: you have it for sure, that's why you get the error `pathToProjectInsideProject/file.php is in submodule pathToProjectInsideProject`. Try to find it with `find /pathToProject/ -name ".git*"` or even `find /pathToProject/ -name ".gi*"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60604/discussion-between-manolo-and-pomeh).

Answer (score 0):

There is a interactive way to add files using git shell.

`git add -i`

```
*** Commands ***
  1: status       2: update       3: revert       4: add untracked
  5: patch        6: diff         7: quit         8: help
What now> 4
  1: New Text Document.txt
  2: s/New Text Document.txt
Add untracked>>
```

So add the files if less in number. Or else use git commit tool which gives interactive UI.

EDIT:

`*` indicates the file is added to track

[image]

Comment: This doesn't change anything. When I try to add a file I get *Huh (pathToProject/pathToProjectInsideProject/aFile.php)?* and it's not added.

Comment: Is the file given to you by git ? Or you are typing it ?

Comment: I'm typing it. I've updated my question.

Comment: Well, git it self shows the untracked files and numbers associated to them. You need to type the number of the file that you wish to track the file. See the image for details

Comment: I've seen it, but there are no untracked files...